# Predicting problem hardness based on feature vector

Tags: correlation, data-mining

Given some optimization problem. For each instance of this problem I can obtain a number of features, say [p1, p2,..., pn]. Features could be for example: number of customers, number of vehicles, costs, etc. I have several different algorithms which can solve problem instances. After solving an instance, I obtain 2 important quality metrics:
1. t: Time (in seconds) it took to solve this instance. Typically, the higher this value, the harder the instance.
2. q: Quality score of the solution (value between 0 (best) and 100 (worst)). If the problem could be solved within the time limit, the score is always 0, otherwise the score is a value greater than 0. The closer the score is to 100, the harder the instance.

Given  [p1, p2,..., pn], t, and q for a large number of problem instances. I would like to identify which features (or subset of features) make the problem hard to solve? Trivially, larger problem instances are harder to solve, but what about instances of a fixed size? Are there features which make the problem particularly hard to solve?

Q1: What kind of analysis should I perform to investigate this? I suppose there are some machine learning tricks? I'm not sure what to search for.
Q2: Are there (academic) tools/software which can perform the desired analysis? This analysis is meant to improve the computations section of a paper, so it shouldn't be too much effort to compute, and certainly not a research project on its own.
Q3: Is there a way to order the features from [explains hardness of instance well] to [does not affect the complexity of the instance]
Q4: Is there a good way to support these findings visually?

To support my question, a small example:

Example data:
Instance [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13] q t
A-2-20-3 <2, 20, 143, 20, 71.5, 1, 172, 6, 0.03, 23.25, 2692, 106, 25.4> 0 1756
A-2-20-4 <2, 20, 111, 20, 55.5, 1, 159, 7, 0.04, 23.95, 1666, 97, 17.18> 0 1943
A-3-5-3 <3, 5, 224, 8, 74.67, 1.6, 57, 7, 0.12, 27.88, 8948, 146, 61.29> 0 113
A-3-10-0 <3, 10, 242, 18, 80.67, 1.8, 160, 11, 0.07, 25.33, 6320, 189, 33.44> 0 293
A-3-10-1 <3, 10, 215, 16, 71.67, 1.6, 147, 9, 0.06, 19.19, 7081, 171, 41.41> 0 556
A-3-10-3 <3, 10, 203, 14, 67.67, 1.4, 103, 10, 0.1, 25.86, 5839, 127, 45.98> 0 339
A-3-10-4 <3, 10, 187, 14, 62.33, 1.4, 146, 5, 0.03, 24.71, 4298, 122, 35.23> 0 127
A-3-15-0 <3, 15, 233, 27, 77.67, 1.8, 240, 9, 0.04, 25.04, 4411, 116, 38.03> 0 2786
A-3-15-1 <3, 15, 202, 23, 67.33, 1.53, 201, 6, 0.03, 22, 3852, 107, 36> 0 1652

This is a very small sample, where all q values equal zero, but in the real set there are many more instance with non-zero q. As you can see, the values of t are rather different. Which features (p1, .., p13) are responsible for this? Is it perhaps a higher value of p13 together with a low value for p5, or does the computation time increase the closer p9 gets to the value 0.5?